# A landlord must provide free internet access, can he charge a deposit for the router?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, tenant

Had an interesting conversation with a friend about what would happen in such a situation.

Let's suppose the contractual term was:

"Internet must be provided free of charge to tenants".

But a landlord may for obvious reasons want a small deposit paid to secure the router.

Could a landlord demand such a deposit, or would it be a breach of the term?

Comment: If it is in the contract, then they can charge it. If it isn't in the contract, then it may cause issues. Depends on the wording, what does this (hypothetical) contract say about deposits?

Comment: "But a landlord may for obvious reasons want a small deposit paid to secure the router." -  for what reason? I would think it is covered by the deposit usually required by property rental agreements.

Comment: Internet access and router are not the same.   Garbage pick up an garbage can are not the same.

Comment: I would argue it depends on the purpose of the router.  If this is their router, and you are simply being provided WIFI access, then no, it would be a breach of agreement to charge a deposit.   If the router is optional, and it would be possible to connect to the Internet without it (ie a single computer could connect, but a router would be needed to share the connection or provide WIFI acces), then charging would be reasonable.

Comment: Also, what exactly does "secure the router" mean?   If it means "secure their router - ie configure it with security controls", then no, you should not be paying a deposit for that - as its a cost they have regardless and not something they can get back when you leave.    (Secure the router could also mean "buy/acquire the router")

Comment: @davidgo: Perhaps I am improperly transposing terms, but I read "deposit" in conjunction with "secure" as "security deposit", i.e. money paid to ensure that the router is returned in good condition, less normal wear and tear.